# Identify World War 2 European theater PC wargame circa 1995

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to identify a World War 2 European theater PC game, which I used to play on a Windows 95 PC, but probably predates Windows 95.

The one thing that really stands out in my memory is that if the British won the game would play a small portion of "It's a Long Way to Tipperary." The music was very crude, not much more than a bunch of beeps.

The game shows a map of England, France, Germany, and Italy. It does not include Russia and you can only play as Britain / US or Germany. I seem to recall the game starting after the fall of France, but maybe there were different scenarios.

The movement was point to point. You could see borders between cities but the units moved basically from city center to city center.

The units were shown as a simple national flag and were infantry, armor, or artillery. It was turn based. Each turn consisted of 1 side recruiting, moving, attacking, and researching new technology (for example you had to research amphibious landings before you could attack across sea areas), followed by the next player turn.

You could play 2 player or against the computer and if you played against the computer there was an option to switch sides at any point.

I've gone through every "abandoned" old game site I could find and while I've found similar looking games none are the one I'm looking for. Vague I know, but worth a shot.

Comment: maybe 'storm across europe" ?

Comment: Does "every 'abandoned' old game site" include the Internet Archive? https://archive.org/details/classicpcgames?and[]=world+war&sin=

Comment: Storm Across Europe is in the ballpark but the game I am looking for has better graphics. I spent quite a bit of time looking through the archive link, but no luck. Thanks

Comment: Note that "It's a Long Way to Tipperary."  is a song from the First World War

Comment: @mmmmmm yes but this is definitely a World War 2 game and it definitely plays that song

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little late, but I think I know the answer. It is called "WW2 in Europe" by W. R. Hutsell.

I played countless hours of this when I was younger and your description reminded me of this game. The key here is "The units were shown as a simple national flag." That is clearly not the case for Clash of Steel. It is the case for WW2 in Europe, which I remember downloading off of DOS shareware sites as ww2107.zip.

> 1 or 2 player strategy level game of World War II in Europe,
> based on the successful VGA Civil War Strategy game approach.
> Includes over 50 key city locations, 5 army types (infantry,
> armor, artillery, elite, and static) and air force and naval
> capabilties. Uses 8 distinctive technologies to upgrade combat
> and production. Has Play by Mail feature. Includes multiple
> scenarios, user-accessible combat and other parameters. Weather
> and other factors included. Recruit armies, conduct air strikes
> and naval bombardments, build fortifications, make paratroop
> drops, conduct invasions, and improve technology. Game play is
> easy, but game has depth, features, and flexibility to make it a
> continuing favorite.

Here are some sources:

1. https://hutsellgames.com/world-war-ii/
2. https://www.gamers.org/pub/archives/uwp-uml/adventure/ww2107.txt

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is absolutely the game I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the game you're looking for is Clash of steel.

The hint that lead me to it was the comment about Storm across Europe being in the ballpark. Wikipedia states it was: "everything that Storm Across Europe should have been and wasn't".

My arguments for:

- predates windows 95 and has better than Storm Across Europe graphics
- map of western Europe with "city to city" turn based advancement, you can search youtube for gameplay
- 2 players vs pc option
- fall of France scenario
- units shown as flag and turns consist of research/move/attack

What I find as arguments against are:

- no boundaries between cities
- not actually moving from city to city but rather dot to dot
- not actually using national flags for units

If this is not the game you're looking for perhaps it would help narrow the ballpark further  :)

Comment: Very nice compendium of evidence!